# Should the focus be set on the first field on a mobile app registration form on screen load?

Tags: forms, mobile-application, focus

Should I set the focus to the first field on a registration form when the screen loads? This means that the keyboard is then in view and will obscure the rest of the form from the user.

The alternative would be to wait until the user selects a field before activating the calendar.

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A registration form is something that you do **only once** and **focusing by default on a field is not a common behaviour** that users might be familiar with on mobile platforms, so I think it will bring more confusion than good experience.

Additionally, it's recommended to give users the control. I understand that this is be a very simple form, but users won't know it until they scroll down, so **you could make them think, which is bad** when you can avoid it.

The only exception I could think of is that you were sure that most of your users have really big screens and the bottom limit of the page is really clear and above the keyboard (everything is "above the fold"), which I don't think it's the current situation for anybody taking into account that for example, 4 inch screen keyboards cover around 40% of the screen.

I would go with the classic approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you allow the user to focus manually because, as you say, it will obscure the rest of the form. Users might find it jarring and they would likely prefer to know what they're about to start filling out :)